# useGetList fetched data sorted by id ignoring sort option

Tags: react-admin

The problem is that data fetched by *useGetList* is sorted by ids of the objects and ignores the order by other keys given by my backend. This is my call example (try to order by name):

```
 const { data, loading } = useGetList(
    'my-controller-path',
    { page: 1, perPage: 10000 },
    { field: 'name', order: 'ASC' },
    {}
  )
  console.log(data)
```

When I print data after this call, data is sorted by 'id' and not by 'name'. It's not a problem with the backend because I hardcoded returning data to eliminate this from equation. Data provided from backend:

```
data: [
  { id: 2, name: 'Ana'},
  { id: 3, name: 'Bea'},
  { id: 1, name: 'Cena'}
]
```

And when I print data on console after using *useGetList*:

```
[
  {id: 1, name: "Cena"},
  {id: 2, name: "Ana"},
  {id: 3, name: "Bea"}
]
```

Any idea what is causing the problem? I read the source code of *useGetList* and don't quite understand if the problem lays there. The [link](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-core/src/dataProvider/useGetList.ts) to source code.

Answer (score 0):

How does your API works ? In my case, I needed to map the `sort` properties like so:

```js
getList: async (
  resource,
  { pagination: { page, perPage }, sort: { field, order }, filter }
) => {
  const query = {
    ...filter,
    sort: order.toLowerCase(),
    order: field,
    page: JSON.stringify(page),
    limit: JSON.stringify(perPage),
  };
  ...
}
```

in my custom data provider to match my API `sort` and `order` properties.

Comment: I hard-coded my API so on every call for that resource, I would return fixed data as I mentioned above. So even if the arguments of useGetList() have some problems, I eliminated it. It does not matter which arguments I sent, because on every call the server returns an fixed array of objects sorted by name.

Seems like useGetList re-sort somewhere between my API returning the array and giving the array to client side. I fixed the problem by sorting on client side, but that's not the best solution in my opinion.

Comment: Ok I get it, try to reproduce it with a minimal example on a fork of https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-violet-2modw. If you can reproduce it, this is a bug on react-admin itself and I suggest to post a new issue on the repository directly.

Comment: Ok, I will try it during the weekend. I did not know official way of reporting the bug till now, so thank you for your time and help.

Comment: You did good to start on SO, from the maintainers if you can produce a minimal example this is probably a bug from react-admin and you can submit an issue on Github for investigations, if you can't, the problem is probably on you side.